# K8s Container are removed by topology Manager after particularly 4 hours

Tags: kubernetes

I am using `Kubeadm 1.19.3 version` & Flannel as cni.
I do not see any resource overutilization on my underlying node.
Below is the Kubelet log around the same timestamp:

> Jan 07 18:35:53 vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107 18:35:53.667179
> 7593 log.go:181] http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from
> k8s.io/kubernetes/vendor/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/server/httplog.(*respLogger).WriteHeader
> (httplog.go:217) Jan 07 18:36:56 vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107
> 18:36:56.756426 7593 topology_manager.go:219] [***topologymanager]
> RemoveContainer - Container ID:
> 32346f17b258c75f77dba18796414a51b58c442c16d66a18a6f1ca32002c0bb8 Jan
> 07 18:37:03 vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107 18:37:03.273923 7593
> reconciler.go:196] operationExecutor.UnmountVolume started for volume
> "defaul***t-token-m9l42" (UniqueName:
> "kubernetes.io/secret/3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4-default-token-m9l42")
> pod "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4" (UID:
> "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4") Jan 07 18:37:03
> vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107 18:37:03.273966 7593
> reconciler.go:196] operationExecutor.UnmountVolume started for volume
> "wta" (UniqueName:
> "kubernetes.io/nfs/3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4-wta-sun-trunk-wta-pv")
> pod "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4" (UID:
> "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4") Jan 07 18:37:03
> vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107 18:37:03.335585 7593
> operation_generator.go:788] UnmountVolume.TearDown succeeded for
> volume
> "kubernetes.io/secret/3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4-default-token-m9l42"
> (OuterVolumeSpecName: "default-token-m9l42") pod
> "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4" (UID:
> "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4"). InnerVolumeSpecName
> "default-token-m9l42". PluginName "kubernetes.io/secret",
> VolumeGidValue "" Jan 07 18:37:03 vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107
> 18:37:03.374229 7593 reconciler.go:319] Volume detached for volume
> "default-token-m9l42" (UniqueName:
> "kubernetes.io/secret/3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4-default-token-m9l42")
> on node "vmcipind83wsfd2" DevicePath "" Jan 07 18:37:03
> vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107 18:37:03.803952 7593
> operation_generator.go:788] UnmountVolume.TearDown succeeded for
> volume
> "kubernetes.io/nfs/3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4-wta-sun-trunk-wta-pv"
> (OuterVolumeSpecName: "wta") pod
> "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4" (UID:
> "3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4"). InnerVolumeSpecName
> "wta-sun-trunk-wta-pv". PluginName "kubernetes.io/nfs", VolumeGidValue
> "" Jan 07 18:37:03 vmcipind83wsfd2 kubelet[7593]: I0107
> 18:37:03.893440 7593 reconciler.go:319] Volume detached for volume
> "wta-sun-trunk-wta-pv" (UniqueName:
> "kubernetes.io/nfs/3516986a-f43b-498e-82e9-4ca11a3c3cd4-wta-sun-trunk-wta-pv")
> on node "vmcipind83wsfd2" DevicePath ""

Comment: Do you have any issue with your NFS storage?

Comment: NFS storage seems to be fine